# React Native: Marking posts a user has seen on his activity feed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, feed, relayjs

I am implementing an activity feed similar to facebook or twitter's. I fetch newsfeed items in batches of x(I use RelayJS, x is the pagesize of connections). However, it may so happen that due to eager loading in the List View a lot of items are fetched for the news feed but the user doesn't scroll to the end to view them. How can I determine what news feed items a user has really seen so that I don't repeat them and only show the newer ones and the ones down below that were fetched but not shown to the user when he refreshes or opens the app next time? The easier solution is to discard all the x items that had been fetched as seen.

How is this info stored? A table of numUsers X numItems with booleans? A set of such items?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on your implementation. The most simple one would be return to the user only the information generated after their last login.

Now, if you want to actually keep track of the information that was actually seen by the user then I guess that is a lot more complex. Like storing every item ID and a flag to check if the user has seen it.

Then you can make a clean up on app close that will mark that very first item that you need to show them that they haven't seen. For example:

1 Not Seen
2 Not Seen
3 Seen
4 Not Seen
5 Not Seen
6 Seen
7 Seen
8 Seen
9 Seen

Upon closing the app, you store that you need to show them starting on the ID 5.

Comment: I also want a way to detect that items 3,6,7,8,9 were seen. Mounting them does not imply they were seen. Do I need to track scroll height to know what items have come to viewport?

Comment: I guess you can track them on the onLayout event. I assume "seen" means the user passed scroll the items. Another way to do it is yes, how you just said. You could query the position of the listview and calculate where the use ir to decide if the item is seen or not. Seems like a lot of work thou.